# WatchBoxBuilder is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In flutter watchboxbuilder is deprecated, can someone help me with this,the full code is [here on the 143 line](https://github.com/imSanjaySoni/Inshorts-Clone-The-News-App/blob/master/lib/common/widgets/news_card/news_card.dart)

```
child: WatchBoxBuilder(
                              box: Hive.box<Articles>('bookmarks'),
                              builder: (context, box) => Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () => handleBookmarks(article),
                                    child: Text(
                                      article.title,
                                      style: box.containsKey(article.url)
                                          ? AppTextStyle.newsTitle
                                              .copyWith(color: AppColor.accent)
                                          : AppTextStyle.newsTitle,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      maxLines: 4,
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WatchBoxBuilder is replaced with box.listenable().

Here is new code,

```
 child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                              valueListenable: Hive.box<Articles>('bookmarks').listenable(),
                              builder: (context, box,child) => Column(
```

For more info
https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter/changelog#0301